# I can not use calendars hosted on the server with Thunderbird and Lightning

Tags: email-server, thunderbird, caldav

I am trying to use [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) and [Lightning](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) to use caldav calendars.

Still does not work. I have no experience with calendars, you likely have some things wrongly configured.

I installed [cyrus-imapd-2.4.17-caldav-beta9](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Latest_Updates) and also use cyrus murder. All in a Debian 8.

On the client side I have Thunderbird 24.2.0 and Lightning 2.6.4 in a Windows XP.

After creating the calendar that is in a state of disabled. When I try to enable it I get this again disabled but not shows me errors.

The steps I follow when creating a new calendar are:

- Select the "On the Network" option and click Continue.
- Select "CalDAV" as the Format.
- Enter a URL of the following form as the Location: http://frontendwin.org/dav/calendars/user/myanez/Default/
- I press next and assign a name to the calendar.
- The associated mail account that I leave the list of options with which I have configured for this user in thunderbird and mail server.

Where: myanez is the name of a user that I created and I started the session by logging on to Thunderbird.

In the settings I had in server and that is working for sending and receiving mail, I add the following lines.

In /etc/imapd.conf add the following line:

```
httpmodules: caldav carddav
```

In /etc/cyrus.conf: add the following line:

```
http            cmd="httpd -U 30" listen="8008" prefork=0 maxchild=100
```

I could trap errors when trying to create a calendar by following these steps:[debug](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:GDATA_Provider#Enabling_calendar.debug.log).

I show the error that I have obtained:

```
CalDAV: send: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:CS="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"><D:prop><D:resourcetype/><D:owner/><D:current-user-principal/><D:supported-report-set/><C:supported-calendar-component-set/><CS:getctag/></D:prop></D:propfind>

CalDAV: Status 405 on initial PROPFIND for calendar Majito
```

I'm forgetting some step in the configuration?.

Thank.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the problem by changing the url, Add port 8008 to it.

http://frontendwin.org:8008/dav/calendars/user/myanez/Default/

Comment: I could fix this error Status 405 while still another error, my answer
was based on that.
The documentation explains caldav imap cyrus on lightming.
If you knew you could not because they did not tell me?. Thanks for puntuarme negatively!....